# Как сделать выборку из объекта БД на Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Уже есть объект:

```
$posts=DB::table('post')->get();
```

Как из него выбрать элементы, у которых свойство 'city' равно '1', не обращаясь заново к бд и не используя циклы для перебора. Нужно что-то типа

```
$selected=$posts->where('city','1')->get();
```

Есть в laravel такая возможность?

Comment: А почему не используешь модель?

Comment: Модель в отличие от DB почему-то возвращает слишком сложный объект с данными о подключении, protected-fillabble и др. ненужными здесь свойствами. Сложно поддается перебору такой объект,так как нужно знать название массива, конкретно содержащего выборку

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$selected=$posts->where('city','1')->all();
```